# How to display Database Value In a Table?

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

[image: Why The Data Cant be displayed?]

I need your help for solve my problem. I have problem while selected a data from database into a table tbody. I have try to made it and try to run it. but the data can't be displayed. I separated the file HTML, PHP, and Javascript in different file type. Please help me..! I would appreciated if you give me an example.

**This is the HTML, PHP, and JQUERY CODE**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="table_s" id="table_s" class="table_s">
    <table id="table_s" class="table_s"cellspacing='0' class="js-serial" border="2">
        <thead>

      <tr>
                <th><center>No.</center></th>
                <th><center>S1</center></th>
                <th><center>S2</center></th>
                <th><center>S3</center></th>
                <th><center>S4</center></th>
                <th><center>S5</center></th>
                <th><center>S6</center></th>
                <th><center>S7</center></th>
                <th><center>S8</center></th>
                <th><center>S9</center></th>
                <th><center>S10</center></th>
                <th><center>S11</center></th>
                <th><center>S12</center></th>
                <th><center>Ambien</center></th>
                <th><center>Average</center></th>
                <th><center>Deff</center></th>
                <th><center>Status</center></th>
      </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="td_s0"></td>
            <td id="td_s1"></td>
            <td id="td_s2"></td>
            <td id="td_s3"></td>
            <td id="td_s4"></td>
            <td id="td_s5"></td>
            <td id="td_s6"></td>
            <td id="td_s7"></td>
            <td id="td_s8"></td>
            <td id="td_s9"></td>
            <td id="td_s10"></td>
            <td id="td_s11"></td>
            <td id="td_s12"></td>
            <td id="td_s13"></td>
            <td id="td_s14"></td>
            <td id="td_s15"></td>
            <td id="td_s16"></td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" id="ajaxButton"/>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
              type: "Post",
              url: "employee.php",
              success: function(data) {
                var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['no']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor1']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor2']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor3']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor4']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor4']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor6']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor7']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor8']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor9']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor10']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor11']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['sensor12']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['ambien']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['average']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['deffiasi']+"</td>";
                    tr += "<td>"+data['status']+"</td>";
                    tr += "</tr>";
                $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
              }
        }); 
    });
});
```

```html
<?php
//connect to the mysql
$db = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Could not connect database");
@mysql_select_db('silo', $db) or die("Could not select database");

//database query
$sql = @mysql_query("select no,s_tanggal,silo,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3,sensor4,sensor5,sensor6,sensor7,sensor8,sensor9 from termocouple");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

//echo result as json
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: So where is html?

Comment: Try to `console.log(data)` and give the output here

Comment: sorry wrong sent.. i've edit the code

Comment: **Don not** use the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 and were removed in PHP 7.0. The old MySQL extension has some security issues. Use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is the Result but only get one record. i have 3 record from database]data is two dimensional
[image: And the second screenshot after i click]
**Recommend using mysqli or PDO**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "employee.php",
            success: function(data) {
                var list = JSON.parse(data);
                var tr = "";
                $.each(list, function(i, v) {
                    tr = +"<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['no'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor1'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor2'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor3'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor4'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor4'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor6'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor7'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor8'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor9'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor10'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor11'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['sensor12'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['ambien'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['average'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['deffiasi'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + v['status'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "</tr>";
                });
                $("#table_s tbody").append(tr);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: btw.. how to make it selected all data ? it just selected single data

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: that code just selected one row only. how to get the all record? using fetch array?

Comment: You code is already read all data, only one data in your database?

Comment: my database has 3 records. but i dont know why it just display only one record

Comment: i send you the screenshot

Comment: it still same..
it just showing one record and looping to right continously when button clicked

Answer (score 0):

You obtain an array form your json_encode

so you should access by index eg: for index 0

```
  tr += "<td>"+data[0]['no']+"</td>";
```

and you may be you need  a  jsonData = JSON.parse(data) eg:

```
   jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
   tr += "<td>"+jsonData[0].no +"</td>";
```